# Unexpected GeometryReader view behavior inside a VStack

Tags: swift, swiftui

Can someone explain why:

`GeometryReader` positions its contents to the left top corner, not in the center.
`GeometryReader` takes up all available space.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                    Text("Hello, World!")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.7, height: 40)
                        .background(Color.red)
            }
            .background(Color.yellow)

            Text("More text")
                .background(Color.blue)
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it looks:

[image: GeometryReader top left]

I would expect it to position `Text` "Hello, World" view in the center.

Comment: *GeometryReader takes up all available space*. This is intended, please read https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/understanding-frames-and-coordinates-inside-geometryreader

Comment: The post explains "get all available space" but no clue about alignment, @vadian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to make some critical changes to get what you're expecting. The reason it is appearing like this is because you're not using Geometry Reader in the way that you think it's supposed to be used. **Geometry reader is essentially a way to get the parent view's size.** Typically you won't use it to layout views and you'd still stick with VStack, ZStack, and HStack nested inside of the geometry reader. This is because the reader expands to take up as much space as possible across the `X and Y` planes. A typical structure to do what you're expecting might look like this. Which ultimately would center "Hello World" inside the center of the geometry reader.

```
GeometryReader { reader in 
    VStack {
         Spacer()
         HStack {
             Spacer()
             Text("Hello World")
             Spacer()
         Spacer()
    }
}
```

Comment: Still don't get it why the view is not centered by default. Usually SwiftUI puts things in the middle if not told otherwise.

Comment: Because it's not used for layouts. Content added, eg the `VStack` in this example, is added at size, drawn from top-left to bottom-right. It has no modifiers to manage content inside and requires a view of some flavor to be added. Again, its purpose is for providing the size of a parent view, not for layouts.